# How to seecurly store Encryption keys/Api keys at client side java application?

Tags: security, encryption

I have a client side java application (web application running on client machine). I want to store encryption keys at client application to encrypt/decrypt some data. More over i also want to store API keys for calling my REST services from client application.

How can i store these keys securely at client side to ensure that they don't get tempered or stolen ?

I was thinking about using java keystore but again question remains same as how to securely store keystore password?

Any suggestions on this ?

Comment: This question has been asked a billion times.  You can't safely store API keys client side. It's the users device and they can do what they want with it. Use a remote server to handle requests on behalf of client devices and store the API key there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. This is like giving someone a locked box and trying to keep the key to the box secret by taping it to the bottom of the box.

Trying to increase this by using a keystore is like putting the key in a separate smaller box, and locking that with a different key which is then taped to the bottom of the box.

If you want any real increase in security, you'll have to make the client ask the server for a key whenever the box needs to be opened, preferably using a password or some other token that it is acceptable for the client to have access to.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, I think there is "better than nothing" solution to use Windows Credential Manager with this Java solution https://github.com/dariusz-szczepaniak/java.jna.WindowsCredentialManager

I'm not a security specialist but I think this would give some extra protection as a hostile attacker would need to know username/password for the client machine to get to the passwords/certificates/keys in Windows Credential Manager.